# Nested decorators, raising 404

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have view

```
def foo(request)
```

I'm also using custom user model as follow:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    field = models.BooleanField()
```

I'd like to combine 2 django decorators: login_required and user_passed_test, so that anonymous user should be redirected to a login page and user who is not allowed to see the view (user.field == False) should see a proper message (say, something like 'you're not allowed to see this').

So I tried:

```
my_decor = user_passes_test(lambda user: user.field == True,
                        login_url='/bar')  


def custom_decor(view_func):
    decorated_view_func = login_required(my_decor(view_func), login_url='/login')
    return decorated_view_func
```

And I also have to define view:

```
def bar(request):
    return HttpResponse('you are not allowed to see this context.')
```

and hardcode it in my urls.

The question is: can I do this without creating an additional view and adding it to urls? Is there a way to make 'user_passed_test' decorator raising an 404 error instead of redirecting to a login view?

There is probably a very simple solution and surely I'm just missing it.

Comment: You are talking about 2 things: 1. combining 2 decorators and 2. modifying the one's behaviour to raise a 404 instead of redirecting. Concerning combining, I think you absolutely do it right.

Answer (score 1):

I dont remember very well the decorators syntax, but you can do:

```
def custom_decor(view_func):
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if request.user.field is True:
            return view_func(request, *arg, **kwargs)
        raise Http404

    return decorator
```

so...

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
@custom_decor
def foo(request)
    # ...
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but unhelpful. The OP wants to combine them, and AFAICT he does it exactly the right way....

Comment: Hm. So maybe I should combine decorator written above with 'login_required'?